# Compile boost as universal library (Intel and Apple Silicon architectures)

Tags: c++, boost, arm64, xcode12, apple-silicon

I am trying to build boost library as dylib on MacOS. I need to build it for both the Intel architecture and the upcoming Apple Silicon (arm64) architecture.

I downloaded boost and ran the following commands:

```
./bootstrap.sh
./b2 -address-model=64 architecture=combined -a
```

`lipo -archs` always shows produced dylibs architecture is `x86_64`.

I have Xcode12 beta and MacOS Catalina 10.15.7,

I can build a sample universal library if I create a project in Xcode and set `archs arm64 x86_64` in build settings.

Running command `./b2 cxxflags="-arch arm64 -arch x86_64"` fails with following errors:

```
    "clang++" -x c++ -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -m64 -O3 -Wall -fvisibility=hidden -Wno-inline -arch arm64 -arch x86_64 -ftemplate-depth-255 -fvisibility=hidden -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -DBOOST_ALL_NO_LIB=1 -DNDEBUG -I"." -c -o "bin.v2/libs/serialization/build/clang-darwin-12.0/release/link-static/threading-multi/visibility-hidden/polymorphic_xml_iarchive.o" "libs/serialization/src/polymorphic_xml_iarchive.cpp"

...failed clang-darwin.compile.c++ bin.v2/libs/serialization/build/clang-darwin-12.0/release/link-static/threading-multi/visibility-hidden/polymorphic_xml_iarchive.o...
clang-darwin.compile.c++ bin.v2/libs/serialization/build/clang-darwin-12.0/release/link-static/threading-multi/visibility-hidden/polymorphic_xml_oarchive.o
In file included from libs/serialization/src/polymorphic_xml_oarchive.cpp:16:
In file included from ./boost/serialization/config.hpp:18:
In file included from ./boost/config.hpp:57:
In file included from ./boost/config/platform/macos.hpp:28:
In file included from ./boost/config/detail/posix_features.hpp:18:
In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/unistd.h:71:
In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/_types.h:27:
In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:32:
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/sys/cdefs.h:807:2: error: Unsupported architecture
#error Unsupported architecture
 ^
In file included from libs/serialization/src/polymorphic_xml_oarchive.cpp:16:
In file included from ./boost/serialization/config.hpp:18:
In file included from ./boost/config.hpp:57:
In file included from ./boost/config/platform/macos.hpp:28:
In file included from ./boost/config/detail/posix_features.hpp:18:
In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/unistd.h:71:
In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/_types.h:27:
In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:33:
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/machine/_types.h:34:2: error: architecture not supported
#error architecture not supported
 ^
In file included from libs/serialization/src/polymorphic_xml_oarchive.cpp:16:
In file included from ./boost/serialization/config.hpp:18:
In file included from ./boost/config.hpp:57:
In file included from ./boost/config/platform/macos.hpp:28:
In file included from ./boost/config/detail/posix_features.hpp:18:
In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/unistd.h:71:
In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/_types.h:27:
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:55:9: error: unknown type name '__int64_t'
typedef __int64_t       __darwin_blkcnt_t;      /* total blocks */
        ^
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:56:9: error: unknown type name '__int32_t'; did you mean '__int128_t'?
typedef __int32_t       __darwin_blksize_t;     /* preferred block size */
        ^
note: '__int128_t' declared here
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:57:9: error: unknown type name '__int32_t'; did you mean '__int128_t'?
typedef __int32_t       __darwin_dev_t;         /* dev_t */
        ^
note: '__int128_t' declared here
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:60:9: error: unknown type name '__uint32_t'; did you mean '__uint128_t'?
typedef __uint32_t      __darwin_gid_t;         /* [???] process and group IDs */
        ^
note: '__uint128_t' declared here
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:61:9: error: unknown type name '__uint32_t'; did you mean '__uint128_t'?
typedef __uint32_t      __darwin_id_t;          /* [XSI] pid_t, uid_t, or gid_t*/
        ^
```

Answer (score 9):

I'm on Monterey with an M1 (XCode 13.1) and failed to get any of the other answers to work, but I combined stuff from [Navan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64824630/3649117) and [Petr](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65566831/3649117) along with some other bits to get the libboost_coroutine to work on x86_64.  I arrived at the following script which builds all the boost libraries (why not, it doesn't take long on the M1):

```
#!/bin/sh

rm -rf arm64 x86_64 universal stage bin.v2
rm -f b2 project-config*
./bootstrap.sh cxxflags="-arch x86_64 -arch arm64" cflags="-arch x86_64 -arch arm64" linkflags="-arch x86_64 -arch arm64"
./b2 toolset=clang-darwin target-os=darwin architecture=arm abi=aapcs cxxflags="-arch arm64" cflags="-arch arm64" linkflags="-arch arm64" -a
mkdir -p arm64 && cp stage/lib/*.dylib arm64
./b2 toolset=clang-darwin target-os=darwin architecture=x86 cxxflags="-arch x86_64" cflags="-arch x86_64" linkflags="-arch x86_64" abi=sysv binary-format=mach-o -a
mkdir x86_64 && cp stage/lib/*.dylib x86_64
mkdir universal
for dylib in arm64/*; do 
  lipo -create -arch arm64 $dylib -arch x86_64 x86_64/$(basename $dylib) -output universal/$(basename $dylib); 
done
for dylib in universal/*; do
  lipo $dylib -info;
done
```

This script prints out the lipo info for each dylib in the `universal` directory, so you can see quickly that every one has both x86_64 and arm64 inside.  I had the following result, maybe it's useful for you to see if your output matches:

```
Architectures in the fat file: universal/libboost_atomic.dylib are: x86_64 arm64 
Architectures in the fat file: universal/libboost_chrono.dylib are: x86_64 arm64 
Architectures in the fat file: universal/libboost_container.dylib are: x86_64 arm64 
Architectures in the fat file: universal/libboost_context.dylib are: x86_64 arm64 
Architectures in the fat file: universal/libboost_contract.dylib are: x86_64 arm64 
Architectures in the fat file: universal/libboost_coroutine.dylib are: x86_64 arm64 
Architectures in the fat file: universal/libboost_date_time.dylib are: x86_64 arm64 
Architectures in the fat file: universal/libboost_filesystem.dylib are: x86_64 arm64 
Architectures in the fat file: universal/libboost_graph.dylib are: x86_64 arm64 
Architectures in the fat file: universal/libboost_iostreams.dylib are: x86_64 arm64 
Architectures in the fat file: universal/libboost_locale.dylib are: x86_64 arm64 
Architectures in the fat file: universal/libboost_log.dylib are: x86_64 arm64 
Architectures in the fat file: universal/libboost_log_setup.dylib are: x86_64 arm64 
Architectures in the fat file: universal/libboost_numpy27.dylib are: x86_64 arm64 
Architectures in the fat file: universal/libboost_prg_exec_monitor.dylib are: x86_64 arm64 
Architectures in the fat file: universal/libboost_program_options.dylib are: x86_64 arm64 
Architectures in the fat file: universal/libboost_python27.dylib are: x86_64 arm64 
Architectures in the fat file: universal/libboost_random.dylib are: x86_64 arm64 
Architectures in the fat file: universal/libboost_regex.dylib are: x86_64 arm64 
Architectures in the fat file: universal/libboost_serialization.dylib are: x86_64 arm64 
Architectures in the fat file: universal/libboost_stacktrace_addr2line.dylib are: x86_64 arm64 
Architectures in the fat file: universal/libboost_stacktrace_basic.dylib are: x86_64 arm64 
Architectures in the fat file: universal/libboost_stacktrace_noop.dylib are: x86_64 arm64 
Architectures in the fat file: universal/libboost_system.dylib are: x86_64 arm64 
Architectures in the fat file: universal/libboost_thread.dylib are: x86_64 arm64 
Architectures in the fat file: universal/libboost_timer.dylib are: x86_64 arm64 
Architectures in the fat file: universal/libboost_type_erasure.dylib are: x86_64 arm64 
Architectures in the fat file: universal/libboost_unit_test_framework.dylib are: x86_64 arm64 
Architectures in the fat file: universal/libboost_wave.dylib are: x86_64 arm64 
Architectures in the fat file: universal/libboost_wserialization.dylib are: x86_64 arm64
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ! It worked for me too ! I was facing a linker issue (the same as reported here : https://github.com/boostorg/coroutine/issues/60) about `_jump_fcontext`, `_make_fcontext`, referenced from boost::coroutines::detail::coroutine_context when trying to compile boost 1.81.0 on my M1 laptop.

Comment: @kamui Thanks for reporting the different error that it fixed for you!  Hopefully it'll help someone with that same error find this solution.

Comment: @JessePangburn this worked well for dynamic libs (.dylib) but is it possible to create static libraries (.a)?  I tried adding `link=static` to the `.b2` commands, but that did not seem to do it.  Any suggestions?

Comment: @JessePangburn please disregard my last comment.  The static libs were creates in `/stage` but the script was globbing `*.dylib` files so they were not being copied into the `/universal` directory.  Many thanks for your script!

Comment: @ariestav Glad to hear it worked for you!

Comment: It works but I get a segfault...

Comment: Ok, so for me it's important to also explicitly state libstd=c++, which is apparently needed if you pass -std=c++11. Then it does not segfault. Background is explained nicely here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19774778/when-is-it-necessary-to-use-the-flag-stdlib-libstdc

Comment: Ok, maybe it was rather for -std=c++11 was needed IF I also use C++11 (or later!?) in my project

Comment: THANK YOU! I spent hours and this is the only solution that works for me. I then did `sudo cp universal/* /usr/local/lib` and that worked perfectly.

Answer (score 5):

The following works for me on Big Sur using Xcode 12.2. On Catalina 10.15.7 (19H15) I get the same error messages as OP.

```
./bootstrap.sh --with-libraries=regex,date_time 
./b2 architecture=combined cxxflags="-arch x86_64 -arch arm64"
```

Comment: What version of Boost were you building here?

Comment: @jamieguinan [Boost Version 1.74.0](https://www.boost.org/users/history/version_1_74_0.html). Version 1.75.0 came out only a few days after I wrote this answer and I haven't tried building that, yet.

Comment: Building 1.75.0 with Xcode 12.4 under Big Sur (on intel) I get the issue mentioned in the response above by Navan Chauhan with this approach - the static libs are universal but the dylibs are only x86_64.

Comment: I tried this for 1.77.0 with Xcode 13.1 under Monterey on M1, but the dylibs were arm64 only.

Comment: Doesn't work. On Intel it compiles for Intel and on M1 it compiles for M1 but never both.

Answer (score 3):

After spending considerable amount of time here:

> https://github.com/bfgroup/b2/issues/105

I was able to compile boost on arm64. The command line is:

> ./b2 architecture=arm address-model=64 asmflags=--target=arm64-apple-darwin21.2.0 cflags=--target=arm64-apple-darwin21.2.0 cxxflags=--target=arm64-apple-darwin21.2.0 linkflags=--target=arm64-apple-darwin21.2.0 -s NO_LZMA=1 -s NO_ZSTD=1 abi=aapcs

the LZMA and ZSTD flags are there since I did not have an universal binary for those libs on my machine.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same issue and came across this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19897761/how-to-make-boost-dylibs-universal-i386-x86-64-on-os-x), which was for creating universal binaries for i386 and x86_64.

To summarise the answer, you need to run `./b2` twice ( with different toolsets as clang always builds for x86_64, even if you pass the appropriate CXXFlags

This is the script I used to first individually generate the libraries I required and then combined them using `lipo`

```sh
#!/bin/sh

rm -rf arm64 x86_64 universal
./bootstrap.sh --with-toolset=clang --with-libraries=thread,system,filesystem,program_options,serialization 
./b2  cxxflags="-arch arm64" toolset=darwin -a
mkdir -p arm64 && cp stage/lib/*.dylib arm64
./b2 toolset=clang cxxflags="-arch arm64 -arch x86_64" -a
mkdir x86_64 && cp stage/lib/*.dylib x86_64
mkdir universal
for dylib in arm64/*; do 
  lipo -create -arch arm64 $dylib -arch x86_64 x86_64/$(basename $dylib) -output universal/$(basename $dylib); 
done
```

Comment: Doesnt work on Monterey, despite "-arm64" and correct config output, this is still producing x86_64 targets

Answer (score 1):

I followed the answer by [Navan Chauhan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64824630/2080250) which seems to be the way to go on macOS 10.15.7 with Xcode 12.3.

My only issue was that the build system was adding additional `-arch armv4t` clang option (or something similar) which fails the build. Using the `architecture=combine` cannot work as well as [it is able to manage Intel and PowerPC only](https://github.com/boostorg/build/blob/632ea768f3eb225b4472c5ed6d20afee708724ad/src/tools/darwin.jam#L453). What does work for me instead is:

1. `bootstrap.sh --with-toolset=clang-darwin` and `cxxflags`, `cflags` and `linkflags` set to `-arch x86_64 -arch arm64` plus additional options.
2. x86_64 build: `b2 toolset=clang-darwin target-os=darwin architecture=x86 stage` and `cxxflags`, `cflags` and `linkflags` set to `-arch x86_64` only (plus additional options).
3. arm64 build: `b2 toolset=clang-darwin target-os=darwin architecture=arm abi=aapcs stage` and `cxxflags`, `cflags` and `linkflags` set to `-arch arm64` only (plus additional options).
4. Merge libraries with `lipo`…

I've been forced to set the ABI also as the *automatic-guess-something* is not able to recognize Apple Silicon goal therefor some assembly stuff is not compiled – hence *missing symbols* later on during the build. Finally the `armv4t` issue is solved by the `clang-darwin` toolset.

The only caveat of this at the moment is that both builds go into the same architectural/configuration directories which can be solved by custom `user-config.jam` or by immediate call to `install` just after each `stage` which is what I did.

Works on:

- Host platform: Intel
- macOS 10.15.7
- Xcode 12.3 (with Command Line Tools installed)
- Boost 1.75.0 (dependent compression and ICU libraries already compiled as universal)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use lipo, you can pass
`-isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk` to cxxflags and it will build a universal library out of the box.

Comment: `./bootstrap.sh --with-libraries=thread,system,filesystem,program_options,serialization && /b2 toolset=darwin -a cxxflags="-arch arm64 -arch x86_64 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk"` does not build a universal library. Checking using `lipo` shows the architecture to be `x86_64` only

Comment: Here is the full command I used:

`# build_boost.sh
./bootsrap.sh

with="--with-exception --with-filesystem --with-test"

cxxflags="-fvisibility=hidden -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -std=c++17 -stdlib=libc++ -arch x86_64 -arch arm64 -mmacosx-version-min=10.11 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk"
cflags="-mmacosx-version-min=10.11"
linkflags="-std=c++17 -stdlib=libc++ -arch x86_64 -arch arm64 -mmacosx-version-min=10.11"`

Comment: Then `./b2 -q -a -j8 architecture=combined toolset=darwin link=static runtime-link=static threading=multi \
cflags="$cflags" cxxflags="$cxxflags" mflags="$cflags" mmflags="$cflags" linkflags="$linkflags" \
--stagedir=stage variant=release $with`

Verify with `lipo -archs libboost_filesystem.a
x86_64 arm64`

Make sure you used the latest XCode 12.2 because 12.1 didn't have the arm bits.

Comment: I am not able to reproduce this with your commands, what boost version are you building for? I am trying on `1.74.0`

Comment: Building boost 1.74.0, macOS Catalina, XCode 12.2 + command line tools
The key is using `architecture=combined` along with `-isysroot`.
What errors are you getting ?

Comment: I am building all the libs on Apple Silicon; thread will not build: error: at libs/thread/build/Jamfile.v2:273
error: 64-bit PPC compilation is not supported when targeting OSX 10.6 or later
I guess when architecture=combined, it somehow falls back to PPC64. When I only build the libs I really need, it seems to work, but when linking my program, it complains about missing _jump_fcontext/_make_fcontext/_ontop_fcontext

Comment: Providing `linkflags` did the trick for me.

Answer (score -1):

Checked for macOS M1 building boost 1.82.0, successfully build fat binaries with both architecture included:

```
./bootstrap.sh
./b2 -a address-model=64 architecture=arm+x86
```

To install systemwide:

```
sudo ./b2 -a address-model=64 architecture=arm+x86 install
```

Checked that it linked successfully. Feel free to make sure with:

```
lipo -info /usr/local/lib/libboost_chrono.dylib
Architectures in the fat file: /usr/local/lib/libboost_chrono.dylib are: x86_64 arm64
```

Hope it helps.